# Словарь, удаление по ключу и замена ключей

Tags: python, python-3.x

После удаления из словаря ключи не изменяются. Собственно вопрос, как изменить ключи?

```
    dict = {1:["one","two"]}
```

Содержимое словаря:

```
0 red green
1 blue pink 
2 white black
```

После удаления, допустим по ключу 1 - 1 blue pink, в словаре остается

```
0 red green
2 white black
```

Вооот, и как изменить ключ 2 на 1 ? Или при удалении по ключу 0, изменить 1 на 0, а 2 на 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При условии, что все ключи словаря идут по порядку.

```
def remove_and_recount(dictionary, removable_key):
    dictionary.pop(removable_key)
    for key in range(removable_key + 1, len(dictionary) + 1):
        dictionary[key - 1] = dictionary.pop(key)


dictionary = { 0: [ 'red', 'green' ], 1: [ 'blue', 'pink' ], 2: [ 'white', 'black' ], 3: [ 'yellow', 'purple' ] }

remove_and_recount(dictionary, 2)

print(dictionary) # {0: ['red', 'green'], 1: ['blue', 'pink'], 2: ['yellow', 'purple']}
```

Answer (score 1):

Может вам список нужен, а не словарь?

```
>>> s = [['red', 'green'], ['blue', 'pink'], ['white', 'black']]

>>> for i, item in enumerate(s):
...     print(i, ' '.join(item))
0 red green
1 blue pink
2 white black

>>> del s[1]

>>> for i, item in enumerate(s):
...     print(i, ' '.join(item))
0 red green
1 white black
```

Вариант со словарем и перенумерацией:

```
>>> s = {0: ('red', 'green'), 1: ('blue', 'pink'), 2: ('white', 'black')}

>>> del s[1]

>>> s = {i: s[j] for i, j in enumerate(sorted(s))}

>>> s
{0: ('red', 'green'), 1: ('white', 'black')}
```

Comment: Только индекс может меняться при добавлении\удалении\изменении элементов списков.

Comment: Наверное, это будет лучше... не знаю. Просто первый день в пайтоне что-то делаю. Накатал работу с файлом при помощи словарей, ых. Будем-с переделывать. Спасибо за совет :)